# CAN'T BOOT snd_hda_intel cannot probe codecs giving up

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, kde

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and KDE. Recently it downloaded some updates and said I needed to restart. I restarted and I got this error:

```
 snd_hda_intel cannot probe codecs giving up
```

I was unable to boot!

After restarting again, I was able to roll back to kernel version **5.19.0-40-generic** and it was able to boot. Apparently the kernel version that creates the error above is **6.1.0-1008-oem**.

I am very new to Linux and I don't know if I need this 6.1.0-1008-oem kernel version or where it came from. I pretty much just install the updates that Discover automatically downloads. Should I delete it?

**UPDATE:**
I discovered that I can boot into recovery mode using the 6.1.0-1008-oem version. Only 1 of my monitors is recognized, but everything else seems to work.

---

**UPDATE 2 (2023-04-29):**

I've been trying different things to resolve this and I'm still stuck.

My computer:

```
Ubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma 5.24.7
Kernel: Linux 6.1.0-1008-oem (x86_64)
motherboard: MSI Z590 ACE GOLD EDITION (MS-7D04)
video card: Nvidia GTX 3080
```

When it boots, one of the following scenarios now occurs:

**1:**
I select **6.1.0-1008-oem** with the **nouveau** driver. When I do this, I can login and I get to the KDE desktop. I can see the desktop background image, but no icons or toolbars load, and the system appears to be frozen. I can press CTRL-ALT-F2 to switch to a command prompt, and if I switch back the desktop works again - all icons and toolbars are visible and usable, but 3D games are unusably slow.

**2:**
I select **6.1.0-1008-oem** with any **nvidia** driver (525, 530, etc.). When I do this, I get this error:

```
snd_hda_intel cannot probe codecs giving up
```

I have tried to research what this error means and how to fix it, but nothing I tried has worked. Most of it involved editing or creating files in /etc/modprobe.d (alsa-base.conf, snd_hda_intel.conf, etc).

I'm not sure how the system got into this state or how to fix it. I would prefer to use the nvidia driver, because it had been working fine before with the nvidia driver. The snd_hda_intel error started appearing in the last month or 2 which seems to somehow be linked to the nvidia driver.

I tried running

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

and only installing the nvidia 530 driver but I still get the snd_hda_intel error.

Also, if I go to "Software & Updates" > Additional Drivers I see all the recent nvidia drivers there. If I select one and click Apply Changes, I get a progress bar that indicates it's switching to the one I selected. However, I never get prompted to reboot, which seems strange.

[image: Additional Drivers]

I've tried the nvidia-driver-530-open (proprietary, tested), and the nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary) and they both give the "snd_hda_intel cannot probe codecs giving up" error.

Please let me know what additional information would be helpful in troubleshooting this. I mainly use Ubuntu as an end-user and I don't know all the inner-workings of it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into `snd_hda_intel cannot probe codecs, giving up` on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on a PC that has a RTX 4070 TI. It wouldn't boot. I was able to fix it by:

1. Booting into recovery mode
2. Turning on networking
3. Dropping into root shell
4. Installing Nvidia's drivers using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535`
5. Power cycling once the screen goes blank